# Dual Booting Surface Book 3 - no way to complete installs

Tags: multi-boot, dualboot

I have been trying to install a dual boot on a surface book 3. I tried usb for Win 10, and also Ubuntu and Fedora.

Windows: I got to the install screen but it either froze or otherwise accepted no input from the keyboard or mouse, or touch screen.

Ubuntu and Fedora: the live usbs both booted, the the mouse, touch screen, and keyboard were non-responsive on both.

I would guess a driver issue, but I have no idea how to get a driver pre-install and this happens even with MS Windows. I have been looking online but most results get distracted by the surface pro. I have the Surface Book - the one where the screen can detach from the keyboard and track pad.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. You just have to plug in an external keyboard and mouse and it works fine until the driver gets installed.